# How to integrate a VScode SSH Tunnel and the files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am SSH tunneling (with VScode terminal) and want to edit my files in the tunnel with VScode. 
Can someone please help/provide a guide on how to do this? I can not seem to figure it out. I have see several articles about using remote vscode

Answer (score -1):

Install Code Runner and SSH-FS. 
Config your user setting like this

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal":true,
"code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true,
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"files.eol": "\n",
"sshfs.configs": [
    {
        "label": "label",
        //Must use the root direction "/"
        "root": "/",
        "host": "host",
        "port": port,
        "username": "name",
        "password": "password"
        "name": "name"
    }]
```

Login your server account over ssh by the vscode terminal. Then you can edit and run your code on remote server.